# Error: data binding error msg:No class attribute for 'view' node

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

**Implemented dataBinding in android but it is throwing error in compile time**

**XML code**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sw360dp_260dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sw360dp_45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/apply_jobs_background_xhdpi" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sw360dp_40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sw360dp_20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/applyJobsCompanyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/amarnath_regular"
            android:hint="Company Name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sw360dp_18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Error**

> data binding error ****msg:No class attribute for 'view' node
>       file:C:\Users\Aayush\AndroidStuidoProjects\SkillDostiJobs\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_apply_jobs.xml

Comment: post your java/kotlin class then everyone will understand

Answer (score 15):

Rename view tag in XML from `<view ... />` to `<View ... />` or verify tag names properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the data tag, to define your binding classes.

Comment: It is fixed now, replaced the <view > tag with <View> in my xml..thanks

Comment: @AayushSingh  If you have resolved your issue yourself, consider adding an answer to your question. This will help wanderers who stumble upon this question. Also, your (posted) xml code already has <View> tag instead of <view>.